# cloud formation stack failing route 53 record set, stuck at create in progress

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I am trying to create record set using alias in cf, but when i execute it the cloud formation is stuck at create in progress

```
   mydns:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
       HostedZoneId: hostzone id
       Comment: test record set
       RecordSets:
          - Name: test-ec2auto
            Type: A
            AliasTarget:
              HostedZoneId: Canonical host zone id of ALB
              DNSName: MYDNSNAME
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like in the Name field you are not providing the fully qualified domain name. Please try by providing "Name" field as "test-ec2auto.abc.com."

According to AWS documentation:

> The name of the domain. You must specify a fully qualified domain name that ends with a period as the last label indication. If you omit the final period, Amazon Route 53 adds it.

Required: Yes

Type: String

This could be one of the reason CF is not able to create the entry.